MySQL Delete locking
Mysql is trying to lock the rows which are beyond the range specified
Txn 1 : Executed the UPDATE query
BEGIN;

UPDATE TABLE TEST SET TYPE = 2 WHERE ID = 210;

Txn 2 : Executed the DELETE query
BEGIN;

DELETE FROM TEST WHERE TYPE = 3 WHERE ID >=1 AND ID<=100;

id is the pk value of the table.
Here, Txn 2 delete query started to wait, due to the update operation in Txn 1.
According to the range that i had specified in the where clause in the delete, it should scan only within the range right?
But if i replace the Txn 2 delete query with the below query, it gets executed successfully despite of txn 1 update operation.
BEGIN;

DELETE FROM TEST WHERE ID IN (1,10,20);

